# Automatic start of python script after just plugging the power supply

Tags: python, boot, ssh

I am trying to make the raspberry run my python script as soon as there is power supply.
I have found some ways is to prepaire the rc.local file I did and i tried to execute the rc.local file alone it works but it doesn't work when I just plug in the power supply, nor when  open the puTTY session even not when I open the lxsession (It doesnt run automatically in any of the cases)
my rc.local

```
        #!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
sudo python /home/pi/t3.py  --cascade=/home/pi/s.xml 0 
exit 0
```

Comment: Firstly the `sudo` is unnecessary (and does nothing as `rc.local` is running as root). Remove this and give it a try. It is also possible that something in the Python script is not running; probably because you are not logged in, or paths are not complete.

Comment: as a standard user run "which python" and then use that full path to the python executable. You can also add " 2>&1 /tmp/t3.log" to the end of the line and see what the command generated.

Answer (score 2):

this command needs a few changes to be run perfectly:

```
sudo python /home/pi/t3.py  --cascade=/home/pi/s.xml 0
```

1. get rid of `sudo`, rc.local is already run by superuser
2. put the complete paths there (environment might be not as you remember it)
3. add `&` at the end of command, because `rc.local` is supposed to finish fast
4. redirect outputs so your script does not get stuck when buffer is full

finally your command becomes something like:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/t3.py --cascade=/home/pi/s.xml 0 >/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'su' command instead 'sudo'.  Your command should look like below. Assume that your username is 'pi'.

```
su pi -c '/usr/bin/python /home/pi/t3.py  --cascade=/home/pi/s.xml 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron to run a script on boot of the rpi

`crontab -e`

Add to the last line of the file

`@reboot python /home/pi/t3.py --cascade=/home/pi/s.xml 0`

From this [website](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/running-a-python-script-at-boot-using-cron/)

Comment: I have tried to do this the line I add is write has no problems because I tried to run it from the terminal direct it does, I just added @reboot at the beginning but It still doesn't run  auto! any idea what is the problem

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your cron table?

Answer (score 0):

`rc.local` executes as the final stage of boot. You need to wait until it would normally ask for your login credentials if a screen was plugged in.
At the start of boot, nothing is ready, booting is setting everything up. You could made the boot time faster, though.